# Nodejs, Mongoose failed to upload to heroku with error code H12, H15. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to host my Node, mongoose, express app to heroku (Pass). I am using heroku for the first time. The app is basic Blog with login system. Even after hours of surfing internet and spending much energy i am unable to host it. The log of the error is here

```
2020-05-21T04:16:28.974768+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
2020-05-21T04:16:28.974772+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
2020-05-21T04:16:28.974773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:659:12
2020-05-21T04:16:28.974773+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:481:7)
2020-05-21T04:16:28.974907+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
2020-05-21T04:16:28.975048+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:23) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2020-05-21T04:16:29.327348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-21T04:17:05.597713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=kalovatvatey.herokuapp.com request_id=d997fd6f-7515-4249-b9e7-553ffb60197c fwd="27.34.50.52" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-05-21T04:17:30.629996+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=kalovatvatey.herokuapp.com request_id=a3440026-9dc1-4ffd-a978-d7be5749b4a2 fwd="27.34.50.52" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=55028ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-21T04:18:03.329483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kalovatvatey.herokuapp.com request_id=7ea70ab2-5ae1-409f-bdab-1d79b3a2a389 fwd="27.34.50.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55005ms status=503 bytes= protocol=httpd
```

also the link to git repository is here
https://github.com/kalovatvatey/Blog

Comment: Hey Hemanta,
First off welcome to Stackoverflow Community.

So I just visited your repo and certainly, and I visited your repo, and couldn't find much to worry about, you write very clean code, I appreciate that.

Would you like to help me in helping you by telling me, what method to upload your app on Heroku you are using, for instance, are you using heroku-CLI or are you using github connect to deploy the application?

Comment: Thank you! I am using heroku-CLI. if i can use different method from Heroku-CLI please suggest. and i really appreciate for your instance reply! :-)

Comment: OK @Hemanta 
I am working on your repo I have cloned to better understand the flow,
mind giving me a few hours to figure that out. I'll post the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning your repository, I have figured out the problem in your application deploy on Heroku.

Well a simple work out would be to run the command

```
heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=YOURMONGODBURI

//or If you don't have mongoURI

heroku addons:add mongolab
```

#### Now let me tell you the problem in brief.

So you were taking the `MONGODB_URI` from the environment variables, and since you haven't set the config variable (Environment Variable) in your heroku app, it is unable to connect to mongo and thus your server eventually fails to start and you see that `request_timed_out`  error on the logs.

After seeing your code, there are a few things that I would like to suggest to you, and I hope you find them useful.

So in `express-session` you have done a few things which are deprecated, and you must be seeing the following warnings too.

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option app.js:49:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option app.js:49:9
```

So, in your index.js line number 48, along with the secret, you must also add       `resave: false` and `saveUninitialized: false`.

As shown below:

```js
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new mongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
}))
```

Comment: did it worked for you? i mean i am still getting the same error. and i had configured that earlier as well!

Comment: @HemantaJungXetry Yes, it did worked.
 https://limitless-coast-67340.herokuapp.com/ here is the deploy.

Ok would you try another command: 
heroku addons:add mongolab

Comment: man its working.. you just configured the mongoDB url right?  where am i missing! i will clean my mind and check later. Thanks you so much for the help anyway though! It was really helpful though! @Ashutosh , anf for this heroku addons:add mongolab my card is not being accepted.

Comment: @HemantaJungXetry, I am glad that I could help, that's what this community is for.

YES, All I did was to configure the URL, (Heroku is something You are going to use for a long time if you are sticking to this field) 

So if you want to add a billing, make an account in Kotak 811 Online, you can enable your cards for International Payment in that bank, and thus it will work.

Once Again Glad to help you.